# Replace option value text from selection in WooCommece notification email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

I would like to change the text to the value obtained from a custom field in email

```php
//Add custom billing fields.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'js_sora_add_billing_fields' );
function js_sora_add_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing_gender'] = array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'label'       => __('Civilité', 'sora'),
        'options'     => array(
            ''      => __( 'Sélectionnez', 'sora' ),        
            'mr'    => __('M.', 'sora'),
            'mrs'   => __('Mme', 'sora'),
            'ms'  => __('Mlle', 'sora'),
        ),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Sélectionnez', 'placeholder', 'sora'),
        'required'    => true,
        'priority'    => 10,
        'class'       => array('form-row-first'),
        'input_class' => array('wc-enhanced-select'), 
        'clear'       => true
    );

    wc_enqueue_js( "
        jQuery( ':input.wc-enhanced-select' ).filter( ':not(.enhanced)' ).each( function() {
            var select2_args = { minimumResultsForSearch: 5 };
            jQuery( this ).select2( select2_args ).addClass( 'enhanced' );
        });"
    );
     
    return $fields;
}

// Update the order meta with field value.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'js_sora_field_update_order_meta' );
function js_sora_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_gender'] ) ) { update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_gender', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_gender'] ) ); }
}
```

To replace:

- 'mr' by 'Cher'
- 'ms' by 'Chère'
- 'ms' by 'Chère'

only in email

Comment: I use the shortcode [wec_order_meta key = 'billing_gender'] in the order emails to display the value of the custom field "billing_gender"
Currently if the customer selects the option « M. », His poster
« mr ». I want to change the text « mr » to « Cher »  /  « mrs » to « Chère » /  « ms » to « Chère » only in email.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: @NicoHaase the code works, I ask to change the values of the custom fields in the emails.